# How to find the solutions to $\frac{11}{2} x - \cos x = 0$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the values of $x$ such that $\frac{11}{2} x - \cos x = 0$.

I really don't know how to find the solutions of this equation.  I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: The question basically asks to find the intersection point of two graphs.........y=(11/2)x and y=cosx

Comment: @SujanDutta ... and that's obviously solvable how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An equation which mix polynomial and trigonometric terms do not show explict solutions and numerical methods should be required.

If you consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{11}2x-\cos(x)$$ its derivative $$f'(x)=\frac{11}2+\sin(x)$$ is always positive so only one solution.

Apply Newton method which, starting from a guess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Let us be lazy and start using $x_0=0$. So, this simple method will generate the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 1 & 0.18181818181818181818 \\
 2 & 0.17891658537664712943 \\
 3 & 0.17891585607026614457 \\
 4 & 0.17891585607022005433 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Quite fast, isn't it ? You will learn that we could even do it faster.

**Edit for your curiosity**

Beside Newton, there are [higher order iterative methods](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/newton.html). Using them, still using $x_0=0$, the first iterate for a method of order $k$ is given in the following table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & x_1^{(k)} & \approx & \text{method} \\
 2 & \frac{2}{11} & 0.1818181818 &\text{Newton}\\
 3 & \frac{238}{1331} & 0.1788129226 &\text{Halley} \\
 4 & \frac{28814}{161051} & 0.1789122700 &\text{Householder}\\
 5 & \frac{10459726}{58461513} & 0.1789164437 &\text{no name}\\
 6 & \frac{1265622382}{7073843073} & 0.1789158127 &\text{no name}\\
 7 & \frac{2297105198362}{12839025177495} & 0.1789158574 &\text{no name}\\
 8 & \frac{5053631400166}{28245855390489} & 0.1789158562 &\text{no name}\\
 9 & \frac{21402128966834974}{119621197578720915} & 0.1789158561&\text{no name}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Moreover, "knowing" that $x$ has to be be quite small, we could have used the Taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$ around $x=0$ and limiting to $O\left(x^3\right)$ write $$f(x)\approx \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{11 x}{2}-1$$ the solution of which being $x=\frac{\sqrt{129}-11}{2} \approx 0.178908$ which is already quite good.

Even better, using Padé approximants around $x=0$ and writing $$f(x)\approx \frac{P_{2}(x)}{Q_{n}(x)}$$ and solving $P_2(x)=0$ leads to quite accurate results as shown i the following table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & x & \approx \\
 2 & \frac{77-\sqrt{3265}}{111} & 0.1789173107 \\
 3 & \frac{3 \left(-1199+\sqrt{1645097}\right)}{1402} & 0.1789158655 \\
 4 & \frac{118635-\sqrt{13560037665}}{12226} & 0.1789158556 \\
 5 & \frac{-1624095+\sqrt{6130243687065}}{4761109} & 0.1789158560
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks alot, but i was actually helping to get an analitical solution, not a numerical one. But it's helpful, thanks.

Comment: @OscarGutierrez. Even $x=\cos(x)$ does not show analytical solution.

Answer (score 10):

We can approximate the value of $x$ without Newton's Method or any calculus at all. We can generalize the idea behind [solving for $x$ in $x = \cos(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/) by repeatedly hitting the cosine button on a calculator and noticing that it converges.

---

Rearranging the equation a bit, we are looking for the $x$ such that 
$$
  x = \frac{2}{11}\cos(x)\;.
$$ 
Intuitively we know that such a value of $x$ exists since the graph of $y=\cos(x)$ and the line $y=\frac{11}{2}x$ intersect.

Now let's consider the function $f$ defined as $f(\_) = \frac{2}{11}\cos(\_)$. Suppose that we repeatedly apply $f$ to some input $a$, and let this infinite composition equal $x$. So we are going to say
$$\begin{align}
   &f\left(f\left(\dotsb f(a)\right)\dotsb\right) 
   \\=\;\;&
   \frac{2}{11}\cos\left(\frac{2}{11}\cos\left(\dotsb \frac{2}{11}\cos(a)\right)\dotsb\right) 
   \\=\;\;& x
\end{align}$$
But if we suppose this converges as the number of times we apply $f$ approaches infinity (so $x$ actually exists and is a number), applying $f$ one more time shouldn't change the value of anything. So we now have 
$$\begin{align}
   &x
   \\=\;\;&
   f\left(f\left(\dotsb f(a)\right)\dotsb\right)
   \\=\;\;&
   f\left(f\left(f\left(\dotsb f(a)\right)\dotsb\right)\right)
   \\=\;\;&
   \frac{2}{11}\cos\left(\frac{2}{11}\cos\left(\frac{2}{11}\cos\left(\dotsb \frac{2}{11}\cos(a)\right)\dotsb\right)\right)
   \\=\;\;& \frac{2}{11}\cos(x)
\end{align}$$

So the $x$ that this may converge to, the $x$ that we are looking for, is precisely the $x$ the solves the equation $x = \frac{2}{11}\cos(x)$. Furthermore we know such an $x$ exists by the reasoning of intersecting graphs above! And since there is no $a$ in the equation $x = \frac{2}{11}\cos(x)$, that must mean the value of $x$ doesn't depend on $a$. This means we can approximate the value of $x$ in $x = \frac{2}{11}\cos(x)$ by taking any number and repeatedly applying $f$ to it.

We can now easily calculate this value of $x$ by programming the function $f(\_) = \frac{2}{11}\cos(\_)$ into a calculator repeatedly apply $f$ to some (any) input. Calculating $f^n$ for different values of $n$ (mostly to compare to Newton's Method in Claude Leibovici's answer) I get:

\begin{array}{c|c}
  n      & f^n(1) \\\hline
  1      & 0.\color{#A00}{0982367828} \\
  2      & 0.1\color{#A00}{809415720} \\
  3      & 0.178\color{#A00}{8499431} \\
  4      & 0.17891\color{#A00}{79884} \\
  5      & 0.178915\color{#A00}{7870} \\
  6      & 0.17891585\color{#A00}{83} \\
  \vdots & \\
  100    & 0.1789158560
\end{array}

So this doesn't converge as quickly as Newtons' Method, but I think that this can be punched into a calculator much quicker.

Comment: Nice, reminds me when I discovered this when repeatedly pressing $\sqrt{Ans+1}$ on my calculator. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599163/sequence-related-to-solutions-of-the-equation-xx-c. This is called the fixed point theorem, which you most likely are already are aware of. This link might be of interest to the OP.